# OpenAL is only making noise when I try to play a wav-file with 2116kbps, what is wrong?

Tags: python, wav, noise, openal, bitrate

I am trying to play a wav-file with the bit rate 2116kbps with Python using the [OpenAL library](https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenAL/) but it only produces white noise. What am I missing?

The audio file is working properly if I use VLC-player. The file also works fine if I reduce the bit rate to 1411kbps.
I am running Python3.7.2

```py
>>> import openal
>>> source = openal.oalOpen("test.wav")
>>> source.play() # Makes white noise
```

Answer (score 0):

With openAl you need to keep checking if the file is still playing

```
while source.get_state() == AL_PLAYING:

time.sleep(1)
```

And don't forget to close it

```
oalQuit()
```

Comment: Doesn't really make any difference

Comment: You might want to check some of your computer codex, because for me it works perfectly fine with .wav file (on windows 10)

Comment: If there was something wrong with the codec on my computer, wouldn't it affect other media players as well?

Comment: I am not sure, but i tested the same code on my machine and it worked well, so there might be an underlying problem